# Suddenly an Apache error? Fatal error: Uncaught Error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I'm accessing remotely the mysql database through the url of a browser, then suddenly I got this error. My computer only has this error. When I tried to access the `192.168.x.x/phpmyadmin` using another pc, I have no error. Why is happening?

This is the error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function checkConfig()
>   on integer in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php:690 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\index.php(12): require_once() #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php on line 690

Comment: this is not programming related, ask in superuser maybe ?

Answer (score 4):

This is the phpMyadmin code where you are getting the Fatal error:

File: common.inc.php

```
/**
 * @global PMA_Theme_Manager $_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager']
 */
if (! isset($_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager'])) {
    $_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager'] = new PMA_Theme_Manager;
} else {
    /**
     * @todo move all __wakeup() functionality into session.inc.php
     */
    $_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager']->checkConfig();
}
```

It seems that `$_SESSION['PMA_Theme_Manager']` maybe was not correctly initialited or your current session in server has a problem or is corrupted.

Are you tried to close your current browser session?. Also you can try open with another browser and surely it works.

Comment: fix: delete cookies in current browser for phpmyadmin

Answer (score 0):

If you tried with another browser (or incognito) and it works,
And you tried deleting your browser cache, cookies etc and still doesn't work,
And you don't care about your users sessions,
Here is how you can delete the PHP sessions and it worked fine for me for the same problem:

GEt your PHP sessions path on server:

Deleting your PHP Sessions:

```
php -r 'echo session_save_path();'
```

My case it is: **/var/lib/php/sessions**

Go to that directory and delete ALL sessions OR sort by date and delete the sessions at about the problem occurred.